# Extend already compiled flutter application functionality through plugins

Tags: flutter, plugins, module, extend, architect

Is it possible to extend the functionality of an already compiled flutter application by plugins or modules developed/compiled by other developers and placed in a specific folder inside, for example, the application folder? If so, what would be the approach to follow (at a high level)? I did this with other languages/technologies, but I don't find info about how to implement this in flutter.

To contextualize the question, I'm making an app in flutter to learn how to use it in which I get information about a given movie through apis to third party services. I would like to see if, once the app is developed, users can increase the number of information sources by making the app compatible with apis to additional third party services.

Best regards and thanks for your time.

(Sorry for my poor English that makes my question maybe too dry and not very clear )

Comment: Found any info on this yet?